# ACL Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spring-security-acl

Is [Grails spring security acl plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-acl) is used in the `Grails services` only so I can't use it in `Grails Controllers`

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile but I think this might be because of how the annotations work. I wrote the Enforcer plugin, to be more flexible, and address the many issues I had with the Spring Security ACL plugin. You may want to give that a look.